# Page transition (slide-in) not working with CSS3

Tags: css, css-transitions, transition

I am creating a single-page website where my content slides across the page (from left to right, easing in over 1s) when a link is clicked on. Unfortunately, I am having absolutely no luck with getting transitions to work.

I can get the .content class to transition using :hover, but cannot seem to achieve any transition/animation effects otherwise. Ideally, I would like the #home, #portfolio, #contact and #cv to be the elements that slide in, but have had no luck for hours now.

I wonder if it is due to the set up of having a sleeve containing all of my slides?

This is my CSS code for the relevant section:

```
#sleeve { 
        position: relative;
        top: 35%;
        width: 400%;
        z-index: 2;
        height: 60%;
    }

#home, #portfolio, #contact, #cv {
        background: aqua;
        width: 25%;
        margin: 0;
        position: relative;
        z-index: 2;
        float: left;
        height: 100%;

-webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
-ms-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
transition: all 1s ease-in-out; 
    }

#home:target ~ #header #navigation #home,
#portfolio:target ~ #header #navigation #portfolio,
#contact:target ~ #header #navigation #contact ,
#cv:target ~ #header #navigation #cv { 
    background: white;
margin-left: 0%;
}


.content {
width: 70%;
min-height: 40%;
margin-left: 15%;
margin-right: 15%;
margin-top: 2%;
background-color: white;
z-index: 5;
position: relative;
}
```

and this is my HTML:

```
<body>
<div id="header"> 
<div id="navigation">
    <a id="link-home" href="#home">   home  </a>
    <a id="link-portfolio" href="#portfolio">   portfolio   </a>
    <a id="link-contact" href="#contact">   contact   </a>
    <a id="link-cv" href="#cv">   cv  </a>
</div>
<h1> ---- :</h1> <h2>portfolio and work</h2> 
</div>

<div id="sleeve">

<div id="home"> 
    <div class="content"><p> home</p> </div>
</div>

<div id="portfolio" class="panel"> <p> portfolio </p> </div>
<div id="contact" class="panel"> <p> contact </p> </div>
<div id="cv" class="panel"> <p> cv </p> </div>
</div>

<div id="footer"> copyright ----- 2013 </div>
</body>
```

I would be eternally grateful for anyone's help!

Answer (score 0):

From the way you have it set up, it looks like you are trying to create a carousel that is responsive? If that's the case you will still need some JS to update the css, like add another class. At the moment there is nothing to transition as your css is not changing.

Answer (score 0):

Check this, it will help you to understand, this is made in Jquery, but you can find another solution more hard coded(if this doesn't solve your problem I can help).

http://www.w3schools.com/jquerymobile/tryit.asp?filename=tryjqmob_trans_reverse

if `<a href="#pagetwo" data-transition="slide">` it will slide to the div with id "pagetwo"

if `<a href="#pageone" data-transition="slide" data-direction="reverse">` it will do an reverse data-direction and will come back to the div with "pageone" and will slide in the reverse way.

Hope this helps.